# Dynamically choose thumbnail for sharing with facebook API - javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are working on updating our site to use the v2 facebook API. With v1, we did the sharing as follows:

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      name: $('title').val(),
      display: 'popup',
      link: url,
      picture: fbImg,
      caption: 'Compute information about '+$("#i").val()+'.'})
     });
```

We used some javascript to dynamically pick the thumbnail image and would store it in `fbImg`.

With v2, it appears that there is no longer a simple picture parameter. Instead it seems that we must define a static image to be used with the `og:image` meta tag.

We've found that a dynamic image can be used using method `share_open_graph`:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'og.shares',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
  object: 'http://' + longUrl,
  image: imageVariable
  })}, function(response){});
```

This is v2 compliant, but the action type `og.shares` was just a guess, which oddly seems to work. `og_shares` is not documented, and a google search for it turns up nothing. This makes us very hesitant to just use that code in production..

Is there a "correct" way to dynamically pick an image for a facebook share using the v2 api?

Comment: Just use og:image and share a unique url. It makes a lot more sense

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by share a unique url?

Comment: Each user should get pretty much a unique url, so can I just use js to inject the image into the meta tag? (before the share is done)

Comment: You can not inject it using Javascript. Facebook scraper will fetch the site at some other point and will not run Javascript

Comment: Is this not possible then? The only way for us to dynamically pick the image is using javascript. We have to grab images which come into the page asynchronously and then make an ajax request to some other resource to calculate the image which will be used.

Comment: Share a unique url. And when someone curl that url you set og:image to the image